# How to cancel the Toggle while pressing left or right arrow key ( from keyboard ) in UWP ToggleSwitch

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have used the ToggleSwitch in my UWP application. All are working perfect. While pressing Left or right arrow key when the focus in ToggleSwitch means, the toggled state is changed. I need to change the behavior by pressing left or right key when focus in ToggleSwitch, but the KeyDown event if not fired while pressing left or right arrow key. But the Toggled event has been fired. In this event, i am not able to get which key is pressed.

Can anyone help me how to cancel the toggle state while pressing left or right arrow key while focus in ToggleSwitch ?

```
<ToggleSwitch Name="toggleSwitch" Header="WiFi" OffContent="Show" OnContent="Hide" />
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/toggles

View of ToggleSwitch : 
[image]

In this when pressing left arrow key means, the toggled state is changed, i need to cancel that toggle by pressing left or right arrow key ( from keyboard ).

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Elavarasan M

Comment: What do you mean by left or right key? can you add its xaml or the screenshot of ui?

Comment: i have attached the UI in above. Please refer here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/toggles to know more about the toggleswitch.

Comment: Did you try istabstop = false? Just a guess..

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now its not get toggled while pressing left or right arrow key as well as up or down key. Only toggled when doing the toggle with mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `IsTabStop="False"`

```
<ToggleSwitch Name="toggleSwitch" Header="WiFi" OffContent="Show" IsTabStop="False" OnContent="Hide" />
```